# usort is returning array in reverse order

Tags: php

This usort function is returning the array reverse from what I want. It's returning an array like ("1", "2", "3"). How can I make it return ("3", "2", "1")?

```
usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
    return $a["comments"] - $b["comments"];
});
```

Comment: `return $b["comments"] - $a["comments"];`

Answer (score 41):

Just reverse the parameters?

```
usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
    return $b["comments"] - $a["comments"];
});
```

Starting PHP7.4 you can write it like this:

```
usort($myArray, fn($a, $b) => $b["comments"] - $a["comments"]);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
    return $b["comments"] - $a["comments"];
});
```

Just change A to B and B to A.

Answer (score 4):

you can reverse your function outputs.

```
usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
    return $b["comments"] - $a["comments"];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```php
usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
    if($a['comments'] === $b['comments']) {
        return 0;
    }

    return ($a['comments'] > $b['comments']) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: You could use spaceship operator and arrow function instead. Why do you make this so complicated?

Comment: @Dharman This is similar to the official documentation examples. Example # 1 of https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: Exactly like Dharman said, generally comparing $b & $a like so in PHP7.4+: `usort($myArray, fn($a, $b) => $b <=> $a);`

Answer (score -3):

```
$myArray  = array("1", "2", "3");
$reversed_array = array_reverse($myArray);
```

Comment: I don't think that this is a valid answer. What if `$myArray` is not sorted yet?